# Add icon to the Outliner editor?

Tags: python, add-on

Can an addon insert a new icon for every object, collection, etc, to the Outliner editor? If so, what is the required python code?

I also want to bind this to a custom property.

Edit: To extend... I would like for the addon to manage a state property for the object and visualize that state in the scene tree that Blender presents.  In the same way that the "eye" icon is used to hide/show objects. But for my use-case, to define what object should be exported outside Blender.

Comment: Hello shumy, I have a very hard time understanding your question. Would you mind elaborating a little further?

Comment: AFAIK, No it is currently not possible from python.