# How can I recolor Blender icons in outliner?

Tags: interface, customization, outliner

I'd like to recolor standard icons from outliner, so the difference between collections, meshes cameras, and lights would be more noticeable.

Here is an example: on the left side you see the original outliner, on the right what I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: …You can recolour the collection icons with the right click context menu. But it looks like both the [icon graphics](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/124614/) and the [Outliner draw](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/192264/) code are [hardcoded into Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/91276/), so IDK if there's a good way. Maybe if you could trick [a custom icon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32335/) into a name collision? But IDs seem to be randomly generated, and it probably wouldn't affect C-level code even otherwise.

Answer (score 9):

For the collections right click the collection.
[image]

For other icons: go to *Edit > Preferences > Themes*
[image: - List item]

Comment: _Edit_ > _Preferences_ > _Themes_ won't help her get the result she's asking for, because you can only change the color for objects in general. Her example shows different colors for a camera object and a mesh object - so that you can visually distinguish between different kinds of objects.

Comment: True. It is not the thing I am trying to achieve T_T